# HTML.Raw equivalent DataAnnotation in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any annotation equivalent to `@Html.Raw(Model.Property)` in ViewModel?

I'm trying to use `[DisplayFormat(HtmlEncode=false)]` with no success to create HTML tags (`<b>`, `<span>`) instead displaying it as text.

Comment: The thing is that any annotation will still require a wrapper around the value, generally `Html.DisplayFor`. So, now you're typing `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)` instead of `@Html.Raw(Model.Property)`. If your goal is saving typing, then that doesn't help you. The only solution that will help is @m0sa's simply because you could then just write `@Model.Property`

Comment: Not saving typing, but (can't explain exactly why) somehow I see `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)` more cleaner or "ok" than `@Html.Raw()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `UIHint` to do this by creating a template `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Html.cshtml` with this inside:

```
@model string
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

Then on your model:

```
[UIHint("Html")]
public string MyHtml {get; set;}
```

This can then be output in all other views as:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyHtml)
```

Comment: In my case, I'm not seeing how UIHint w/ Html.Raw comes to a solution where just using Html.Raw works (I want to leave .cshtml a bit cleaner from Helpers by moving formattings to ViewModel as possible).

Comment: IMO, I prefer to do it like this. I only end up with one html.cshtml file in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\ and I simplify my model by only specifying the UIHint, in all other views I do not have to do @Html.Raw.

Comment: Ah! really like it! I didn't get it at first sight. The @Html.Raw will be placed into template, I thought it was at .cshtml. Think I didn't wake up yet this morning.

Comment: Just one correction: you have to output the value using `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyHtml)`. Otherwise, the display template doesn't go into effect.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Very good point Chris, in my demo app here I had that but forgot. Thanks, updated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make the property an `IHtmlString` (you can use the [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) implementation) instead of a `string`.

```
public class MyModel 
{
     public IHtmlString Property { get; private set; }
     public MyModel(string property)
     {
          Property = new MvcHtmlString(property);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I won't like to create a new property just to avoid @Html.Raw, I don't hate it so much. hehe!